# Flush all messages in mailbox from Zimbra to another server

Tags: postfix, dovecot, zimbra

I have a primary Dovecot + Postfix mail server and a secondary Zimbra 8.0.1 server. The primary server went down for a week and all the incoming messages were delivered to the secondary server which has configured a "catch all" account. Now that the primary server is back online, I'd like to flush all messages on the "catch all" mailbox to the primary server for appropriate delivery to the corresponding user mailbox (and its own rules). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/).

```
imapsync --buffersize 81920000 --nosyncacls --subscribe --syncinternaldates --fast --host1 server.zimbra.tld --user1 user@zimbra.tld --password1 badasspass --tls1 --host2 server.dovecot.tld --user2 user@dovecot.tld --password2 lalala --tls2
```

*excerpt from website*

> The purpose of imapsync is to migrate IMAP accounts or to backup IMAP accounts. IMAP is one of the three current standard protocols to access mailboxes, the two other are POP3 and HTTP with webmails (often tied to an IMAP server).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `fetchmail`. That software acts as POP/IMAP client and fetch messages from Zimbra and then send them via SMTP to the primary MX.